# How to call another frame when countdown ends in SWING

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, countdown

I am making an examination system desktop application in Java Swing.
I have a frame named 'show_class_question' frame.
This frame is used to display questions and four options from database.
Whenever user clicks 'Next' button I am calling this same frame (show_class_question) again and again from itself (self - referencing) upto total number of questions (say 20).

**show_class_question** --(user clicks next button on it)--> **show_class_question**

Now I would like to add a countdown timer, whose value will be retrieved from database. I have stored minutes in database in an int column.
And whenever user clicks next button the remaining time is passed to the same frame (show_class question) along with other values.

**This process continues unless user:**

1. answers all question
2. or clicks on 'End exam' button
3. or when the countdown becomes zero

When any of the above happens I want to call 'user_Result' frame

My problems are I am not able to pass remaining time in correct way whenever user clicks 'next' button.
Although I somehow managed to manipulate the countdown code I got from internet and passed the remaining time on next frame, but the 'user_Result' frame is being called several times. Suppose I clicked 'Next' button on 'show_class_question' 7 times, the 'user_Result' frame is getting called 7 times and even before the countdown is zero.

I am posting my code below, I request you to correct it or be genorous enough and provide me with a better and correct way of doing it.

**-Thank you**

```
public class Show_class_question extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Timer timer;
String header_name;
String class_name;
String stream_name;
String u_id;
String mix_course_header;
int d=0;

public void end_exam()
{
 truncate_table();
        User_result ur = new User_result(score, no_of_quest_answered, header_name, mix_course_header,  u_id, negative_marking, points_awarded, points_deducted, difficulty_level, no_of_correct_answers, total_no_of_ques);
        ur.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
}
public void truncate_table()
 {
     try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connection_const.DB_URL,Connection_const.USER_NAME,Connection_const.PASSWORD);
         Statement st = con.createStatement();

         String sqla = "TRUNCATE TABLE asked_ques_table";
         st.executeUpdate(sqla);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}


/*
 * Declaring publics strings for op1 2 3 4 and answer
 */
String ques = null;
String q_id = null;
String op1 = null;
String op2 = null;
String op3 = null;
String op4 = null;
String answer = null;

// declaring logical variables
int flag;
float score;
int no_of_quest_answered;
int no_of_correct_answers;

//Exam pattern variables
String difficulty_level;
 int total_no_of_ques;
 int time_limit;
 int points_awarded;
 int negative_marking; // 0 --> no, 1 --> yes
 float points_deducted;


 // countdown variables

long remaining;
long passed;
long limit;

/**
 * Creates new form Show_class_question
 */
public Show_class_question() {
    initComponents();
}

// our new constructor

public Show_class_question(String h_name, String pclass_name, String pstream_name, int pflag, String pu_id) {
    header_name = h_name;
    class_name = pclass_name;
    stream_name = pstream_name;
    u_id = pu_id;
    flag = pflag;
    initComponents();
}


//self refrencing constructor
public Show_class_question(int pflag, float pscore, int p_no_of_ques_ans, String pq_id, String pclass_name, String pstream_name, String namelb,  String pu_id, int pno_of_correct_ans,  long plimit,long ppassed)
{
    flag = pflag;
    score = pscore;
    no_of_quest_answered = p_no_of_ques_ans;
    q_id = pq_id;
    class_name = pclass_name;
    stream_name = pstream_name;
    header_name = namelb;
    u_id = pu_id;
    no_of_correct_answers = pno_of_correct_ans;
    //remaining = premaining;
   passed = ppassed;
    limit = plimit;
    System.out.println("rem inside cons= "+remaining);


    //x2 = px;

    System.out.println("d cls name= "+class_name);
    System.out.println("d strm name= "+stream_name);

    System.out.println("flag value at top  = "+flag);
    System.out.println("score value at top  = "+score);
    System.out.println("no_of_q_a value at top  = "+no_of_quest_answered);
    System.out.println("q_id value at top  = "+q_id);

    initComponents(); 
}


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  limit=remaining;

    String user_answer;
    if (flag == 0) {

        score = 0;
        no_of_quest_answered = 0;
    }

    if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
        user_answer = jRadioButton2.getText();
    } else if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
        user_answer = jRadioButton3.getText();
    } else if (jRadioButton4.isSelected()) {
        user_answer = jRadioButton4.getText();
    } else if (jRadioButton5.isSelected()) {
        user_answer = jRadioButton5.getText();
    } else {
        user_answer = null;
    }


    //checking answer and answered or not

    if (user_answer != null) {

        no_of_quest_answered++;
       if(negative_marking==0)
        {
            if(user_answer.equals(answer))
            {
                score=score+(1*points_awarded);
                no_of_correct_answers++;
             }
        }
        else if(negative_marking==1)
        {
             if(user_answer.equals(answer))
            {
                 score=score+(1*points_awarded);
                 no_of_correct_answers++;

            }
             else
             {
                 score= (score-points_deducted);

             }
        } 
    }

    flag++;
    System.out.println("flag value at bottom  = " + flag);

    if (flag < total_no_of_ques) //starting frm 0
    {

        Show_class_question s_c_q = new Show_class_question(flag, score, no_of_quest_answered, q_id, class_name, stream_name,  header_name, u_id,no_of_correct_answers,  limit, passed);
        s_c_q.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        truncate_table();
        User_result ur = new User_result(score, no_of_quest_answered, header_name, mix_course_header,  u_id, negative_marking, points_awarded, points_deducted, difficulty_level, no_of_correct_answers, total_no_of_ques);
        ur.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    // user ended exam in between

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "You will not be able to answer any more questions. Continue?");
    if(response==0)
    {
     truncate_table();
    User_result ur = new User_result(score, no_of_quest_answered, header_name, mix_course_header,  u_id, negative_marking,points_awarded,points_deducted,difficulty_level,no_of_correct_answers,total_no_of_ques);
    ur.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
    }
}                                        

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connection_const.DB_URL,Connection_const.USER_NAME, Connection_const.PASSWORD);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        String sql6  = "SELECT pattern_id FROM exam_pattern_in_use WHERE pid = '1' ";
         ResultSet rs6 = st.executeQuery(sql6);
         String pattern_id = null;
         while(rs6.next())
         {
              pattern_id = rs6.getString("pattern_id");
         }
           String sq5 = "SELECT * FROM exam_pattern WHERE pattern_id='"+pattern_id+"' ";
         ResultSet rs5 = st.executeQuery(sq5);
         String db_diff_lev = null;
         String db_time_limit = null;
         String db_tot_ques = null;
         String db_points_award = null;
         String db_neg_marking = null;
         String db_points_ded = null;

         while(rs5.next())
         {
             db_diff_lev = rs5.getString("difficulty_level");
             db_tot_ques = rs5.getString("tot_no_of_ques");
             db_time_limit = rs5.getString("time_limit");
             db_points_award = rs5.getString("points_awarded_for_correct_ans");
             db_neg_marking = rs5.getString("negative_marking");
             db_points_ded = rs5.getString("points_deduced_for_wrong_ans");
         }
         int my_time_limit = Integer.parseInt(db_time_limit);
         System.out.println("my time lim = "+my_time_limit);


    ////------------------------->timer code start here
    final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        if(flag==0)
            limit = my_time_limit*1000; // X seconds

             timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
             long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
             passed = time - current;
             remaining = limit - passed;
             System.out.println("rem time ="+remaining);

          if(remaining >= 1) {
              long seconds = remaining/1000;
            long minutes = seconds/60;
            long hours = minutes/60;
            jLabel13.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds%60));


          } else {

           timer.stop();
           timer.setRepeats(false);
           truncate_table();
           setVisible(false);
           dispose();
        User_result ur = new User_result(score, no_of_quest_answered, header_name, mix_course_header,  u_id, negative_marking, points_awarded, points_deducted, difficulty_level, no_of_correct_answers, total_no_of_ques);
        ur.setVisible(true);
           d=1;
        }

       }

        });

      timer.start();

    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // debug/report here

      nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    ////------------------------->timer code end here


    setTitle("Question: "+(flag+1));
    headernmlb.setText(header_name);
    class_name_lb.setText(class_name);
    jLabel10.setText(stream_name);
    mix_course_header = class_name+"-"+stream_name;




    if(flag==0)
    {
        jButton3.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        jButton3.setVisible(false);
    }

          /*  if(d==1)
                  {
                        truncate_table();
                        User_result ur = new User_result(score, no_of_quest_answered, header_name, mix_course_header,  u_id, negative_marking, points_awarded, points_deducted, difficulty_level, no_of_correct_answers, total_no_of_ques);
                        ur.setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose();
                  }
    */

         difficulty_level = db_diff_lev;
         total_no_of_ques = Integer.parseInt(db_tot_ques);
         points_awarded = Integer.parseInt(db_points_award);
         negative_marking =  Integer.parseInt(db_neg_marking);
         points_deducted =  Float.parseFloat(db_points_ded);
         System.out.println("fractional points ded = "+points_deducted);


          String sql = "SELECT s_id FROM school_stream_level WHERE course_name = '"+class_name+"' and stream_name = '"+stream_name+"' ";
          // s_id in class_question_table = c_id in course_level
          // dono 1 hi cheez represent kar rahe he
          // dono me FK relationship he


           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

           String s_id=null;

         while(rs.next())
         {
              s_id = rs.getString("s_id");
         }

          String sql2;

         if(flag==0)
         {
             sql2 = "SELECT * FROM class_ques_table WHERE s_id = '"+s_id+"' and  difficulty_level = '"+difficulty_level+"' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

         }
         else
         {
                  sql2 = "SELECT * FROM class_ques_table WHERE s_id = '"+s_id+"' and  difficulty_level = '"+difficulty_level+"' and q_id NOT IN(SELECT q_id FROM asked_ques_table) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
         }


          ResultSet rs2 =st.executeQuery(sql2);
          System.out.println("under rs2");

              while(rs2.next())
              {
                   ques = rs2.getString("question");
                   q_id = rs2.getString("q_id");
                   op1 = rs2.getString("op1");
                   op2 = rs2.getString("op2");
                   op3 = rs2.getString("op3");
                   op4 = rs2.getString("op4");
                   answer = rs2.getString("answer");
                   System.out.println("q_id db = "+q_id);
              }

                  jLabel7.setText(""+(flag+1));
                  queslb.setText(ques);
                  jRadioButton2.setText(op1);
                  jRadioButton3.setText(op2);
                  jRadioButton4.setText(op3);
                  jRadioButton5.setText(op4);


                  String sql00 = "INSERT INTO asked_ques_table VALUES('0', '"+q_id+"')";
                  st.executeUpdate(sql00);



    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}                                 

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (flag == 0) {
        //   jButton3.setVisible(true);
        School_stream_selection s_s_s = new School_stream_selection(header_name, class_name, u_id);
        s_s_s.setVisible(true);
        dispose();

    }

}                                        

private void jLabel1FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

...and few more lines...
```

Comment: To me, that sounds really inefficient.  Why recycle the frame, when all you really need to do is clear the currently active panel and add the questions to it.  In fact you could pre-load all the questions into a list of `QuestionPane`s and use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to move between the questions.  That way you would simply load the timer once and be able to handle the "alarm" event in a single class...

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)